# Cannot see the builds after publishing the artifacts

Tags: artifactory

I am new to Artifactory and just going through the guides and trying out some sample code.

I am trying to publish a maven artifact to my artifactory server. I have followed the following steps to do it:

1. Through the "Set me up" tool, get the settings.xml file for maven.
2. Download and place the settings.xml file to the ~/.m2 folder
3. Clone the maven example repo from the artifactory examples available on git.
4. Update the pom.xml file and add the distributionManagement tag provided in the "Set me up" window.
5. Publish the code using mvn deploy

The binaries are published to the artifactory server and are available in the Artifact Repository Browser window. But I do not see any corresponding builds in the Build Browser. I also do not get any builds if I try to fetch them using the REST API

What am I missing? I followed the above steps because I saw it on the Introduction to Artifactory webinar video. Is there any setting that I need to change to see the builds in the Build Browser window?

I am using Artifactory Version 5.10.3 (OSS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding, the maven example plugin is used for publishing artifacts to Artifactory, however, it doesn't publish Build Info.

In order for you to publish build info to Artifactory, you will either need to use CI server with Artifactory plugin (for example, Jenkins, Bamboo, Teamcity) or use the Maven Artifactory plugin:

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin

That have the build information publish step inside.